# Re-use of texture unit for different texture types breaks in chrome

Tags: webgl

check out the following test:

http://binks.knobbits.org/webgl/texture3.html

It's a simple test of cube textures.  It also has a 2D texture in there for good measure.

I discovered that in some browsers (so far, chrome) The image is not displayed properly if I re-use the same texture unit for drawing the cube texture as for the 2D texture.

There is a checkbox at the bottom marked "Use separate texture units for the cube texture on the sphere and the 2D texture on the floor" that shows this.

Is this a bug in chrome or in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ordered a bit the code of the drawing functions and now are working.

Square:

```
TexturedSquare.prototype.draw = function() {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.v);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_vertex);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_normal);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_tex1pos);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.va_vertex,4,gl.FLOAT,false,10*4,0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.va_normal,4,gl.FLOAT,false,10*4,4*4);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.va_tex1pos,2,gl.FLOAT,false,10*4,4*8);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,this.texture);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,null);

    gl.uniform1i(shader.textures,1);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.texture1,0);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.cube_textures,0);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.cubeTexture0,1);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,this.e);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES,this.l,gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_tex1pos);
}
```

Sphere:

```
GLHTexturedSphere.prototype.draw = function() {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,this.vbuf);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_vertex);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_normal);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.va_cubetex0pos);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.va_vertex,4,gl.FLOAT,false,8*4,0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.va_normal,4,gl.FLOAT,false,8*4,4*4);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.va_cubetex0pos,4,gl.FLOAT,false,8*4,4*4);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,this.texture);

    gl.uniform1i(shader.textures,0);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.texture1,1);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.cube_textures,1);
    gl.uniform1i(shader.cubeTexture0,0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,this.ebuf);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES,this.l,gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(gl.va_cubetex0pos);
}
```

Both of them are using now `TEXTURE0`. Please check WebGL states and uniform values.

Original code is a bit hard for me, sorry. But I think the problem is that `texture1` and `cubeTexture0` uniforms are been setted with the same value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your code but

1) You can't use the same texture for 2 different targets. In other words you can't do this

```
tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, tex);
```

2) You can't use both a TEXTURE_2D and a CUBE_MAP on a texture unit AT THE SAME TIME.

You can assign both, but when you render you're only allowed to reference one of them in your shaders. In other words.

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
tex1 = gl.createTexture();
tex2 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, tex2);
```

Is okay but a shader that tried use both textures from texture unit 0 would fail.